# Non italic font in displaymath

Tags: math-mode, fonts, equations

I would like to render my math in non-italic font.

I tried various combinations of `mathastext` with no avail and am starting to believe this can't be achieved this way, but looking on TeX-StackExchange that seems to be the proper way.

Is there a simple way of not displaying math in italics, globally?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please be more specific as to what you've tried so far. E.g., which options did you set when loading the `mathastext` package? Please also provide information about the TeX engine (pdfLaTeX? XeLaTeX? LuaLaTeX? something else?), the document class, and any font packages you employ.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the purpose of this is, except for trying to get really bad typesetting. But here it is.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathastext}

\begin{document}

This document has upright math $a+b=c$ everywhere. It's so bad
that my eyes bleed.
\begin{equation}\label{xx}
\begin{split}
a& =b+c-d\\
 & \quad +e-f\\
 & =g+h\\
 & =i
\end{split}
\end{equation}
A more complicated display
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}\begin{split}
H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
  \sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
  \Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The displays were taken from the documentation of `amsmath`.

[image]

I also tried the same with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (adding `\usepackage{fontspec}`) and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

With `unicode-maths`, use the `[range=it->up]` option. Compile with xelatex/lualatex.

Presumably you aren't using  anywhere.

[image: italic to upright]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand\mfname{Asana Math}
\setmainfont[Colour=blue]{\mfname}
\setmathfont{\mfname}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Colour=red,range={it->up}]
\usepackage{simpsons}


\begin{document}

Unicode (math mode):
$^{2} ∈ _{θ_{i}}$

Unicode (text mode):

{\huge
\hspace{2pt}\textsuperscript{\normalsize 2} ∈ \textsubscript{\Large{θ}\textsubscript{\textit{i}}}
}
\hfill\Left\Burns

x + \mscrL + \BbbN   + \mfrakH + \mbffrakR \ $\mapsto$ \  $x + \mscrL + \BbbN   + \mfrakH + \mbffrakR $
\bigskip

egreg: This document has upright math $a+b=c$ everywhere. It's so bad
that my eyes bleed.
\begin{equation}\label{xx}
\begin{split}
a& =b+c-d\\
 & \quad +e-f\\
 & =g+h\\
 & =i
\end{split}
\end{equation}
A more complicated display
\begin{equation}\label{e:barwq}\begin{split}
H_c&=\frac{1}{2n} \sum^n_{l=0}(-1)^{l}(n-{l})^{p-2}
  \sum_{l _1+\dots+ l _p=l}\prod^p_{i=1} \binom{n_i}{l _i}\\
&\quad\cdot[(n-l )-(n_i-l _i)]^{n_i-l _i}\cdot
  \Bigl[(n-l )^2-\sum^p_{j=1}(n_i-l _i)^2\Bigr].
\end{split}\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Plenty of math alphabets in Unicode, all in the one font file. Here are some:

[image: half of the alphabets]